# How to find the total investment from interest received

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentages

Dave Horn invested half of his money at $5$%, one-third of his money at $4$%, and the rest of his money at $3.5$%. If his total annual investment income was $\$530$, how much had he invested?

I found this, but I was still confused as to why he didn't change the 530, if he was putting 6 into the equation:

6m = total money (choose something it's easy to get half of and 1/3 of)

3m = money at 5% 
2m = money at 4% 
(6m - 5m) = 1m = money at 3.5%

So 0.05(3m) + 0.04(2m) + 0.035 (1m) = 530

Multiply out each, then combine, then divide 530 by the number in front of m after you combine. 
Then plug that in to get each amount.

Comment: Here's what I tried: (1/2 * .05) (1/3 *.04) (1/6 * .035) = 530

Comment: No, you don't want the product of those terms on the left.  If he invests $\frac x2$ at $5\%$, the interest received is $\frac x2 \cdot 0.05$.  Can you do the other two investments?

Comment: So: 
x/2 * .05 + x/3 * .04 + x/6 * .035 = 530

Comment: I got rid of the fractions by multiplying by 6:
3x *.03 + 2x * .24 + .21x = 3180

Comment: 3.3x + 2.24x + 1.21x = 3180

Comment: 6.75x = 3180
x= 471.11

Comment: 471.11/2    471.11/3      471.11/6

Comment: 1/2: 11.77  1/3: 157.03  1/6: 78.51

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ represent the amount invested.

$$0.05\cdot \frac 12I + 0.04\cdot \frac 13 I + 0.035 \cdot \frac 16 I = 530 $$

Solve for I.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: So what? Just rearrange it and solve for I.

Comment: What is 2I, 3I, 6I? 
What is the point if you're going to just tell me what to do.

Comment: Sorry, thought you just wanted the answer. Nice edit by amWhy.

Comment: I formatted the question so you can more clearly see the coefficients of $I$. As it had been formatted, I can understand your confusion, @Ajzimmerman

Comment: Here is what I have, with what you have given me:
.05 * 1/2I + .04 * 1/3I + .035 * 1/6I = 530
.025I + .013I + .0058I = .0438I = 530

Comment: This would mean: I = 12,325
And that 1/2 of his investment: 616.25
1/3: 493
1/6: 431.37
 Obviously incorrect. I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Ajzimmerman You have to be exact. $0.05*1/2I + 0.04*1/3I + 0.035I*1/6=\frac{530}{12000}I=530$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let the whole amount invested be $x$.  How much interest did he receive from he part at $5\%$?  Add up the amount received from each piece, which must total $530$.

Comment: What is X? 
is: (1/2 * .05) (1/3 *.04) (1/6 * .035) = 530 correct?
I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to calculate the Proportion of the investment, (x), which is invested at 3,5%.

It is $1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=a$

Thus the equation is: paid interest investment - investment=530

$\frac{x}{2}\cdot 1.05 +\frac{x}{3}\cdot 1.04+a\cdot x\cdot 1.035-x=530$

Comment: Where did the 1.05, 1.04, 1.035 come from?

Comment: @Ajzimmerman Suppose the interest rate is 0.05=5% p.a. Now you invest 100 dollars. After one year you will have 100 dollars and 5% of 100 dollars: $100 + 0.05\cdot 100$ Now you can factor out 100: $100\cdot (1+0.05)=100\cdot 1.05$ Thus after one year you will have 105 dollars.

Comment: @mistermarko They are both correct.

Comment: Is x/2 representative of the total invested / by 2?
Why is it 1.05, 1.04, 1.035 if you didn't change the 530?

Comment: @Ajzimmerman x/2 is the half of the total investment. That´s correct. The second question I do not really understand. You should fomulate it in another way.

Comment: What I mean is, if you changed the .05, .04, .035 to 1.05, 1.04, 1.035, you should have changed 530 to 530000.

Comment: @Ajzimmerman I do not really change from .05, .04, .035 to 1.05, 1.04, 1.035. I just calculate the investment with interest paid and substract the investment. In the example above the calculation would be $1.05\cdot x-x=5$. $1.05\cdot x$ is the investment with interest paid and x is the investment. The $5 are the interest on investment.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is still confusing to me. I do not understand what you're doing.

Comment: I just pay interest on the investment. For i=0.05 p.a. and an investment of 100 you get 105[$=(1+0.05)\cdot 100$] after a year. To get the total annual investment income (based on the investment), you have to substract the investment: $105-$100=$5.